# How to find Form Id in web part

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I was following this example

enter code here

```
$(document).ready(function ()

{
    $("#FormID").validate({
        rules: {

        ReasonCode: "required"
    },
    messages: {

        ReasonCode: "Please enter ReasonCode"
    }
});

function createSite() {
     $("#FormID").valid();
     return false;
}
```

}

But In my webpart I couldn't find t **#FormID**, I feel like its wired question. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by web part you mean html, then I think you are looking for is the id attribute of the form element.  See the simple code below.
In the form element there is an id.  The # in the #FormID in your jquery is referencing this id

```
<form action="" id="FormID" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname"></input>
    </div> 
        <div>
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname"></input>
    </div> 

</form>
```